# Display user data in alert dialog from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to get a user's information to be displayed in an alert dialog box when their profile is clicked on. I am able to get the dialog box to be displayed when clicked but the dialog box is empty. The users data is being stored in Firebase Real-Time Database.Iv posted the code Im using and added comments to the code. Im guessing the issue is with the Database Reference or the DataSnapshot?

```
    //Variables
    usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    // OnItemClickListener
    flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {

               // users profile card 
            cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
            final String userId = obj.getUserId();

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            DatabaseReference userbio = usersDb.child(userId).child("Bio");
            userbio.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(userId).child("Bio").getValue() != null){
                        userBio = dataSnapshot.child("Bio").getValue().toString();
                    }
                }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            builder.setTitle("Bio");
            builder.setMessage(userBio);
            // Set click listener for alert dialog buttons
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch(which){
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            // User clicked the Yes button
                            break;

                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            // User clicked the No button
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            // Set the alert dialog yes button click listener
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener);
            // Set the alert dialog no button click listener
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",dialogClickListener);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            // Display the alert dialog on interface
            dialog.show();
        }
    }); }
```

[image]

I figured out the issue. I have added the corrected code below.

```
             DatabaseReference databaseReference = usersDb.child(userId);
             databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
                  {
                 @Override
                 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
                   {
                     if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                         if (dataSnapshot.child("Bio").getValue() != null) {
                             userBio = dataSnapshot.child("Bio").getValue().toString();
                         }
                     }}
                 @Override
                 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                 }
             });
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle("Bio");
            builder.setMessage(userBio);
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Okay, I added a screenshot of my database.

Comment: Please also expand what is inside those closed objects.

Comment: I will do! I have posted another screenshot with the objects expanded.

Comment: I see now. The problem is that you cannot simply use `userBio` outside the callback because, the value of that property isn't loaded yet. Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behavior and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its because you are calling twice `child("Bio")`, first in the DatabaseReference and then in the DataSnapshot. Try to delete it from one of them.

Comment: That didn't work. Deleting the child from the Reference caused a crash and deleting the child from DataSnapshot just displayed an empty alert dialog.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your Firebase Database structure about the data you want to obtain?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my database.

Comment: Actually,you were correct. After removing the child from the Database Reference and changing the code a bit I got it to work.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked!